# How to determine when the next puppet agent run will occur?

Tags: puppet

I am running a Puppet Enterprise Puppet Master (version 2016.2) on RHEL7.2.  I think that by default that the puppet agent will run every 30 minutes.  But as I watch for the puppet agent to run I do not see it run.  I look at the reports for my nodes and see there is a report that is 1 hour and 15 minutes old.

I would like to be able to programmatically find out when the puppet agent will run again on a given node.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is this even possible?** - answer is no I'm afraid.

However, true as that may be, I know it doesn't sound very helpful, so here is some extra info :-)

It goes by the runinterval config (see https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/configuration.html#runinterval).

Which as you say defaults to every 30 minutes when running as a daemon. Because the timer is internal, and it doesn't provide an API hook for figuring out when it is going to happen, you just can't determine exactly when it is going to happen. I would say if your runinterval is set high enough that your node should take that long to get a report, then you might want to reduce it. If not, then maybe something has crashed.....